# On resume the fragment i am unable to view the marker and animated camera to a location in map

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I am working on an app with google maps-v2. Everything is working fine but when i go from the map fragment to other fragment and get back to the map fragment its not adding any marker or animating the camera.

Following is the code for the fragment:

```
public class MapPane extends Fragment implements DirectionFinderListener {

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
ProgressBar progressBar;
// Google Map
private static GoogleMap googleMap;
public static double latitude, longitude;
private Button btnFindPath;
private String sOrigin = "";
private String sDestination = "";
private List<Marker> originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Marker> destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Polyline> polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
View v;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_pane, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.m_directions) {

        Fragment frag3 = new DirectionActivity();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft3 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft3.replace(R.id.content_frame, frag3);
        ft3.commit();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("MapPane", "onCreateView()");
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    sOrigin = getArguments().getString("source");

    sDestination = getArguments().getString("destination");
    Log.e("MapPane ", "Source: " + sOrigin + "Destination: " + sDestination);

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    if (sOrigin.equals(null)) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Source is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(sOrigin, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
            longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
            Log.e("Location Coordinates ", String.valueOf(latitude) + " ," + String.valueOf(longitude));
        }
    }

    btnFindPath = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnFindPath);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!checkPermission()) {

        requestPermission();

    } else {

        zoomToOrigin();
    }


    btnFindPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sendRequest();
        }
    });


    return v;
}

private void zoomToOrigin() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
        // Show rationale and request permission.

    }

    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(12).build();

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}

private boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }
}

private void requestPermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission Granted, Now you can access location data.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission Granted, Now you can access location data.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            break;


    }
}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

private void sendRequest() {


    try {
        new DirectionFinder(this, sOrigin, sDestination).execute();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    initilizeMap();
    Log.e("MapPane", "onResume()" + latitude + " ," + longitude);

    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .title("Nagpur");

    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(14).build();

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                Fragment fragment = new BDashboard();
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                ft.commit();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    Log.e("MapPane", "onDestroyView");
    try {
        MapFragment fragment = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}

@Override
public void onDirectionFinderStart() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please wait.",
            "Finding direction..!", true);

    if (originMarkers != null) {
        for (Marker marker : originMarkers) {
            marker.remove();
        }
    }

    if (destinationMarkers != null) {
        for (Marker marker : destinationMarkers) {
            marker.remove();
        }
    }

    if (polylinePaths != null) {
        for (Polyline polyline : polylinePaths) {
            polyline.remove();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Route route : routes) {

        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration)).setText(route.duration.text);
        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDistance)).setText(route.distance.text);

        originMarkers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue))
                .title(route.startAddress)
                .position(route.startLocation)));


        destinationMarkers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green))
                .title(route.endAddress)
                .position(route.endLocation)));

        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
                geodesic(true).
                color(Color.BLUE).
                width(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < route.points.size(); i++)
            polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(i));

        polylinePaths.add(googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));
    }

}

}
```

**This is the only problem i am facing unless everything is working fine.
Please help me to solve this issue.**

**Thanks**

Comment: instead of onResume() try with onAttach(). move and animate your camera in onAttach().

Comment: its not working bro!

Comment: Hi @SwapnilLanjewar, did you solved the issue? I also have the sampel problem